# Font Size is either 0 or 1 (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

I'm using the OpenSans font in my project but when I adjust its size to a value greater than 1, its size doesn't change. If I set its size with 0, it disappears. I don't understand why it behaves like that. Can anyone explain that to me?

Here is the code:

```
let RememberMe = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: checkbox.frame.maxX + view.frame.width*0.05, y: 0, width: ForgetPasswordcontainer.frame.width*0.3, height: ForgetPasswordcontainer.frame.height/2))
RememberMe.text = "Remember Me"
RememberMe.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Regular", size: 1)
RememberMe.textColor = Colors().blue
RememberMe.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
RememberMe.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
RememberMe.textAlignment = .center
ForgetPasswordcontainer.addSubview(RememberMe)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not changing because of this line:

```
RememberMe.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

No matter what you set the size to, once you get to that line you are once again resizing the font to fit the label that the text is contained in. Either remove that line or change the frame of the label. Also, since it is a custom font you need to be sure that you have registered it in your `Info.plist`.

Comment: thanks for your replay , but i removed that line and it still the same  whenever  i set the font size with a value greater than 1 , i have checked the plist and it's registered. and i don't want to change the frame of the label. 
I just want the font size change when i change the value of the size.

Comment: Are you sure that the name of the font you typed in is correct and that the file contains the face you specified?

Comment: yes, i'm sure , when i try different custom font it just works fine , but the OpenSans-Regular has a problem

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me. Please check :

```
RememberMe.font = UIFont(name: "Open Sans", size: 10)
```

And add TTF file to your target.

Answer (score 0):

hey have a look at below code

```
  let RememberMe = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: self.view.frame.size.width  , height: 100))
        RememberMe.text = "Remember Me"
        //This add you to selected font and of minimum size which will be adjusted to width itself so no .. appears
        RememberMe.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Regular", size: 1000)
        RememberMe.textColor = UIColor.blue
        RememberMe.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
        //Need to add this externally if you want to explicitly increase label size
        RememberMe.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 100)
        RememberMe.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        RememberMe.textAlignment = .center
        self.view.addSubview(RememberMe)
```

Output : 
[image]

1) Must see the frame you provide it and thats correct I think as you are taking this label in other subviews

2) need to provide  RememberMe.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 100) this as to give a size to system Label you are adding as to explicitly increase minimum system font size

Hope it helps

Comment: Do your query is Solved ?